# Recursion on a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, character, tuples

I want to make a program that

- takes a character and a list of pairs of characters as arguments,
- returns the first element of the pair if it is equal to the input character, or returns the unchanged pair otherwise.

I have the following code:

```
lookUp :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char    
lookUp a [] = []
lookUp a [(x,y),(xs,ys)]
   | a == x = y : lookUp [(xs,ys)]
   | otherwise = x : y : lookUp [(xs,ys)]
```

When I compile it, I get a lot of mistakes:

> Couldn't match expected type 'char' with actual type [t0]
>
> In an equation for 'lookUp'

and so on...

Sorry, I'm relatively new to Haskell. I'm pretty sure I made a mistake when dealing recursively with the tuple  (`[(x,y),(xs,ys)]`), but I don't know how to change it. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand - do you want a list of Chars? Can you say precisely what you want the function to do?

Comment: If you want to return a value and a pair in different cases, you can wrap the result type in `Either` data type.

Comment: *returns the first element of the pair if it is equal to the input character, or returns the unchanged pair otherwise.* You can't do that. The type of your result cannot differ from one case (`Char`) to the other (`(Char,Char)`). Please clarify your specs.

Answer (score 1):

This modification of your code will type check:

```
-- lookUp :: we'll have GHC tell us the type signature    
lookUp a [] = []
lookUp a ((x,y):pairs)
   | a == x = y : lookUp a pairs
   | otherwise = x : y : lookUp a pairs
```

Some obvious mistakes:

- When you recursively call `lookUp` you only called it with one argument (you forgot the `a` argument)
- The pattern `[(x,y),(xs,ys)]` will only match a list of exactly two pairs of characters. The pattern `((x,y):pairs)` matches a non-empty list of pairs. The first pair is deconstructed into characters `x` and `y` and the remaineder of the list is bound to `pairs`.

Use the `:t` command in `ghci` to have GHC tell you what the type signature is.

Now whether or not this is what you want is another question.